# Caldav server answers with 403

Tags: php, http-status-code-403, caldav

I am trying to connect to the Caldav server with a PHP client. I found this client library http://repo.or.cz/w/davical.git/blob/HEAD:/inc/caldav-client.php and I'm trying to follow the example, domain/username/password exchanged here.

```
$cal = new CalDAVClient( "http://192.168.10.11/caldav/users/domain.com/user-name/", "user-name", "password" );
$options = $cal->DoOptionsRequest();
if ( isset($options["PROPFIND"]) ) {
    // Fetch some information about the events in that calendar
    $cal->SetDepth(1);
    $folder_xml = $cal->DoXMLRequest("PROPFIND", '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><propfind xmlns="DAV:"><prop><getcontentlength/><getcontenttype/><resourcetype/><getetag/></prop></propfind>' );
}
var_dump($folder_xml);exit;
```

That already gives me some 403 Forbidden back:

```
string(1928) "HTTP/1.1 207 Multi status
Connection: Close
Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
Date: Fri, 2 Oct 2015 07:02:28 GMT
DAV: 1, access-control, calendar-access, calendar-schedule, calendar-proxy, calendar-availability, calendarserver-private-events, calendar-auto-schedule, calendarserver-principal-property-search, calendarserver-sharing, calendarserver-sharing-no-scheduling, addressbook, calendar-default-alarms
Server: Kerio Connect 8.5.1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge

584
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><a:multistatus xmlns:a="DAV:" xmlns:c="urn:uuid:c2f41010-65b3-11d1-a29f-00aa00c14882/" xmlns:b="xml:"><a:response><a:href>/caldav/users/domain.com/user-name/</a:href><a:propstat><a:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</a:status><a:prop><a:resourcetype><a:collection/><a:principal/></a:resourcetype></a:prop></a:propstat><a:propstat><a:status>HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden</a:status><a:prop><a:getcontentlength/><a:getcontenttype/><a:getetag/></a:prop></a:propstat></a:response><a:response xmlns:d="http://calendarserver.org/ns/"><a:href>/caldav/users/domain.com/user-name/calendar-proxy-write/</a:href><a:propstat><a:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</a:status><a:prop><a:resourcetype><a:collection/><a:principal/><d:calendar-proxy-write/></a:resourcetype></a:prop></a:propstat><a:propstat><a:status>HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden</a:status><a:prop><a:getcontentlength/><a:getcontenttype/><a:getetag/></a:prop></a:propstat></a:response><a:response xmlns:e="http://calendarserver.org/ns/"><a:href>/caldav/users/domain.com/user-name/calendar-proxy-read/</a:href><a:propstat><a:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</a:status><a:prop><a:resourcetype><a:collection/><a:principal/><e:calendar-proxy-read/></a:resourcetype></a:prop></a:propstat><a:propstat><a:status>HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden</a:status><a:prop><a:getcontentlength/><a:getcontenttype/><a:getetag/></a:prop></a:propstat></a:response></a:multistatus>
0

"
```

Any idea where I could look to fix the forbidden errors? I got no clue why I'm not getting anything.

**edit:**
I finally found some time to look further into this, but only found some logs, no solution yet. Can't figure out what goes wrong yet, but this is what I found in the logs

```
[07/Dec/2015 15:29:51][21240] {https} Task 202600 handler BEGIN
[07/Dec/2015 15:29:51][21240] {https} Task 202600 handler starting
[07/Dec/2015 15:29:51][21240] {https} HTTPS connection from 192.168.10.91:59937 started
[07/Dec/2015 15:29:51][21240] {https} PROPFIND request for URI /caldav/users/mydomain.com/myuser/
[07/Dec/2015 15:29:51][21240] {https} User-Agent header: DAViCalClient
[07/Dec/2015 15:29:51][21240] {webdav} PROPFIND /caldav/users/mydomain.com/myuser/ received from remote host='192.168.10.91', user-agent='DAViCalClient'
[07/Dec/2015 15:29:51][21240] {webdav} PropertyRequestReader: found property "getcontentlength" from namespace "DAV:"
[07/Dec/2015 15:29:51][21240] {webdav} PropertyRequestReader: found property "getcontenttype" from namespace "DAV:"
[07/Dec/2015 15:29:51][21240] {webdav} PropertyRequestReader: found property "resourcetype" from namespace "DAV:"
[07/Dec/2015 15:29:51][21240] {webdav} PropertyRequestReader: found property "getetag" from namespace "DAV:"
[07/Dec/2015 15:29:51][21240] {webdav} (B)PROPFIND: User myuser@mydomain.com is listing properties of principal: myuser<_at_>mydomain.com
[07/Dec/2015 15:29:51][21240] {webdav} User: myuser<_at_>mydomain.com refers to an unsupported property: "getcontentlength" of resource: "" using handler: "PrincipalHandler"
[07/Dec/2015 15:29:51][21240] {webdav} User: myuser<_at_>mydomain.com refers to an unsupported property: "getcontenttype" of resource: "" using handler: "PrincipalHandler"
[07/Dec/2015 15:29:51][21240] {webdav} User: myuser<_at_>mydomain.com refers to an unsupported property: "getetag" of resource: "" using handler: "PrincipalHandler"
[07/Dec/2015 15:29:51][21240] {webdav} (B)PROPFIND: User myuser@mydomain.com is listing properties of principal: myuser<_at_>mydomain.com
[07/Dec/2015 15:29:51][21240] {webdav} User: myuser<_at_>mydomain.com refers to an unsupported property: "getcontentlength" of resource: "" using handler: "PrincipalHandler"
[07/Dec/2015 15:29:51][21240] {webdav} User: myuser<_at_>mydomain.com refers to an unsupported property: "getcontenttype" of resource: "" using handler: "PrincipalHandler"
[07/Dec/2015 15:29:51][21240] {webdav} User: myuser<_at_>mydomain.com refers to an unsupported property: "getetag" of resource: "" using handler: "PrincipalHandler"
[07/Dec/2015 15:29:51][21240] {webdav} (B)PROPFIND: User myuser@mydomain.com is listing properties of principal: myuser<_at_>mydomain.com
[07/Dec/2015 15:29:51][21240] {webdav} User: myuser<_at_>mydomain.com refers to an unsupported property: "getcontentlength" of resource: "" using handler: "PrincipalHandler"
[07/Dec/2015 15:29:51][21240] {webdav} User: myuser<_at_>mydomain.com refers to an unsupported property: "getcontenttype" of resource: "" using handler: "PrincipalHandler"
[07/Dec/2015 15:29:51][21240] {webdav} User: myuser<_at_>mydomain.com refers to an unsupported property: "getetag" of resource: "" using handler: "PrincipalHandler"
[07/Dec/2015 15:29:51][21240] {https} Response: HTTP/1.1 207 Multi status
[07/Dec/2015 15:29:51][21240] {https} Request finished in 0.00 s, received 373 bytes, sent 1916 bytes
[07/Dec/2015 15:29:51][21240] {https} Task 202600 handler END
```

Comment: Well, as always: take a look at the http servers error log file.

Comment: The caldav server is actually part of a Kerio server. I just tried look for logfiles, there are a few... But nothing for a webserver/caldav server whatsoever... I might have to ask Kerio where to find some logfiles actually

Comment: Ah, so Kerio is a commercial server software. I expected it to be something implemented on top of some http server like all other caldav and carddav services. In that case I suggest you contact their support? I would expect you payed for support anyway?

Comment: Yeah it is actually quite commercial and closed up. Didn't think about that... I just asked their forums, we are paying customers, but not sure if this is still part of the support that we pay for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you send the request to the user principal path, not to a calendar collection nor to the calendar home.

The properties [`DAV:getcontentlength`](http://www.davwiki.org/DAV%3A%3Agetcontentlength), [`DAV:getcontenttype`](http://www.davwiki.org/DAV%3A%3Agetcontenttype) and [`DAV:getetag`](http://www.davwiki.org/DAV%3A%3Agetetag) don't need to be defined for resources that don't support the `GET` request. As you can see in the response, the property [`DAV:resourcetype`](http://www.davwiki.org/DAV%3A%3Aresourcetype) actually has a value which says it's a `DAV:collection` and a `DAV:principal`.

I think the developers at Kerio decided to return 403 instead of 404 for these properties, because these properties are not just absent because they have not been set yet, but because they are not applicable to the resource as such.

To find the calendars of your user you need to find the calendar home first. The user's calendars are located beneath his calendar-home.

To find the calendar-home just do a `PROPFIND` for the property [`CALDAV:calendar-home-set`](http://www.davwiki.org/urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Axml%3Ans%3Acaldav%3Acalendar-home-set) on the same path. This will return all calendar-homes (usually that's just one) the user owns.

Comment: yeah, thanks so much! I did as proposed and looked up the calendar-home-set, then found all my calendars had a different path then expected. After using the returned paths, everything worked very smooth!